# When using $.ajax({dataType: 'script'}), request is issued only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

I'm trying to load a dynamic js from server using `$.ajax({dataType: 'script'})`, but request fires only on first attempt (I'm running them from browser console).

Basically, this script is dynamically generated on url `/test/script/`:

```js
alert('test');
```

Then I run from browser:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/script/',
    dataType: 'script',
    type: 'POST',
});
```

and `alert` is issued.

On second attempt though no HTTP request is issued for some reason and `statusText` of `$.ajax` return value is `"canceled"`. Why doesn't it work the second time?

Comment: Why are you making a post request for `script`? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I was emulating rails way of issuing javascript response for POST request. Basically, `POST /foo/update` with some data, get `$('#foo').replaceWith(updatedTemplate)` in response.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? are you trying to response some javascript code by sending ajax call and then trying to run or insert into the document?

Answer (score 0):

Please do a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like @charlietfl said.

Anywhere I give a two posible problems to check:

- You use chrome console, so disable CORS. Exceute in Admin mode chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
- Add cache: true in $.ajax options. Because default is false and it append a random parameter. It's the same cache false and true

  [image]

Comment: `dataType:"script"` Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, `_=[TIMESTAMP]`, to the URL unless the cache option is set to `true`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for clarifying why jquery adds that parameter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured this one.

Basically, the problem was I was using Yii2.
It has its own configs for jQuery in `yii.js` file. [One of them](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-jquery/blob/6c2bd9a1ec6e3e433e7afc68792bbf630ff412d1/src/assets/yii.js#L359), basically, caches ajax requests with type `'script'`. So, unless I set `yii.reloadableScripts = ['<script name>', ...]`, ajax requests with type `'script'` fire only once.

Comment: but dont think of changing it as it would start loading your script twice and will throw errors, as far as i know.